# Como retirar ddd de um número

Tags: php

Por exemplo, tenho um número de telefone salvo em uma variável:

```
$numero = 5198765432
```

Porém, agora preciso retirar o ddd dele (51) para salvá-lo em outra variável. Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: `$numero` sempre terá esse tamanho fixo?

Comment: Sim @RafaelAlmeida!

Comment: Agora fiquei em duvida, você só precisa remover o DDD, ou precisa dele para por em outra variável? Ou precisa de uma formatação tipo `51**98765432`?

Comment: É que vou usar isso para salvar no banco de dados em campos separados, numero_cliente e ddd_cliente! @PapaCharlie

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uma das possíveis soluções é usar [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php).

```php
$numero = 5198765432;
$ddd_cliente = substr($numero, 0, 2);
$numero_cliente = substr($numero, 2);

echo "DDD: {$ddd_cliente} Número: {$numero_cliente}";
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/I5GNXm)</kbd>

Uma outra forma usando o [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php):

```php
$numero = 5198765432;
$ddd_cliente = preg_replace('/\A.{2}?\K[\d]+/', '', $numero);
$numero_cliente = preg_replace('/^\d{2}/', '', $numero);

echo "DDD: {$ddd_cliente} Número: {$numero_cliente}";
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/XjiJME)</kbd>

Comment: Obrigado! Mais simples que eu imaginava :p

Comment: assim estaria certo? `if (strlen($telefone_cliente) > 9 ) {
                $telefone_sem_ddd = substr($telefone_cliente,2);
                $ddd_cliente = substr($telefone_cliente,0,2);
            }
            else {
                $telefone_sem_ddd = $telefone_cliente;
                $ddd_cliente = '00';
            }`

Comment: @GWER Aparentemente está certo sim. =)

Answer (score 4):

```
$numero = 5198765432;
$ddd = substr($numero, 0, 2);
$numero = substr($numero, 2);

var_dump($ddd);
var_dump($numero);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 3):

Apresentando outra abordagem, você pode trabalhar a string como array (mais rápido que `substr`) e recuperar os 2 primeiros caracteres, dessa forma você tem o DDD e o telefone em variáveis separadas.

```
$phone = '5198765432';
$ddd   = $phone[0] . $phone[1];
$phone = substr( $phone , 2 );

// output: 51 ** 98765432
echo $ddd . '**' . $phone;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica, super útil!

Answer (score 3):

Tem várias formas. Uma possibilidade seria substr

```
$numero = substr($numero, 2);
```

Assim ele retira os dois primeiros caracteres da string

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score -1):

Caso o seu input tenha uma máscara e o formato seja `(00) 0000-0000` ou `(00) 00000-0000`, você pode usar REGEX:

```
/**
* Função auxiliar para extrair DDD e telefone de uma string
*
* (string) telefone (00) 0000-0000 ou (00) 00000-0000
* (string) retorno 'ddd' ou qualquer outra coisa para retornar o telefone
*/
function dddTel(telefone, retorno) {
  var ddd;
  // Remove todos os caractéres que não são números
  telefone = telefone.replace(/\D/g, '');
  // (00) 0000-0000 agora é 0000000000, etc
  if (telefone.length === 10) {
    // Telefone fixo
    ddd = telefone.substr(0, 2);
    telefone = telefone.substr(2, 8);
  } else if (telefone.length === 11) {
    // Telefone celular
    ddd = telefone.substr(0, 2);
    telefone = telefone.substr(2, 9);
  } else {
    // Formato não suportado
    console.log('dddTel() falhou. O telefone informado está num formato não suportado.');
  }
  if (retorno == 'ddd') {
    return ddd;
  } else {
    return telefone;
  }
}

// Uso:
var telefone = (31) 9123-45678;
ddd = dddTel(telefone, 'ddd'); // 31
tel = dddTel(telefone); // 912345678
```

Answer (score -3):

Bom, eu tive problemas quando o o número vinha, por exemplo, 55 11 912345678 e o DDD também for 55, então tá aqui um regex que consegue separar o número do país, o ddd e o telefone:

```
$telefone = preg_replace('/[()]/', '', $telefone);

if (preg_match('/^(?:(?:\+|00)?(55)\s?)?(?:\(?([0-0]?[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1})\)?\s?)??(?:((?:9\d|[2-9])\d{3}\-?\d{4}))$/', $telefone, $matches) === false) {
    return null;
}

$ddi = $matches[1] ?? '';
$ddd = preg_replace('/^0/', '', $matches[2] ?? '');
$telefone = $matches[3];
```